# How to conditionally <echo> into a log-file?

Tags: ant, conditional-statements

We need to output some logging entries into a file, but *only when the filename is specified*. The current task reads:

```xml
<echo fileName="${debugLog}" message="${message}"/>
```

Currently, when the `debugLog`-property is not set, it creates a file named, literally "${debugLog}". How can I make it simply skip the task, when the property is not defined?

Our ant is old (1.6.5 - and cannot be upgraded), and the `if:set="debugLog"` attribute is simply ignored, but we use ant-contrib already, and `<if>` is available.

Comment: Which Ant version is it?

Comment: Ant-1.6.5 -- I updated the question with this information now